# com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, resources, managed-bean

I have a JSF managedbean

I am getting the error when a managed bean is referred from from JSF page in WebSphere AppServer.

```
<h:inputText value=#{bean}/>
```

The bean is defined in the faces-config.xml as

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.test.Bean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

This is the exception:

> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean mailingCitySuggestions

---

**Update**: this is the stacktrace:

```
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean mailingCitySuggestions
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:213)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:108)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:374)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:222)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:88)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:506 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.portlet.PortletVariableResolver.resolveVariable(PortletVariableResolver.java:91)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:112)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:45)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.html_extended.TypeaheadRenderer.doAnswer(TypeaheadRenderer.java:278)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.html_extended.TypeaheadRenderer.encodeBegin(TypeaheadRenderer.java:81)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeBegin(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:64)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:802)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:934)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:826)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:507 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:118)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:826)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:118)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:826)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:118)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:826)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:826)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:508 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:289)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:220)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.portlet.PortletViewHandlerImpl.renderView(PortletViewHandlerImpl.java:79)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at hhsc.it.mtp.core.listner.InterceptingLifecycle.render(InterceptingLifecycle.java:84)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doRender(FacesPortlet.java:374)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doView(FacesPortlet.java:415)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at hhsc.it.mtp.portlet.IndividualSearchPortlet.doView(IndividualSearchPortlet.java:36)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doDispatch(FacesPortlet.java:303)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:183)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:573)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:509 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doRender(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:156)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:510 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:214)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:511 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:97)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:119)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:74)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:89)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:512 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$1.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:98)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:182)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:116)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.doRenderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:641)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.render.AbstractRenderManager.performService(AbstractRenderManager.java:264)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:132)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.extension.render.PortletFragmentRenderer.render(PortletFragmentRenderer.java:218)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.extension.render.PortletFragmentRenderer.render(PortletFragmentRenderer.java:166)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPFragmentRenderPhase.processRendering(WPFragmentRenderPhase.java:248)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPFragmentRenderPhase.processRendering(WPFragmentRenderPhase.java:186)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:194)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:97)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:860)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:617)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:513 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:888)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1257)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:648)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1248)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:184)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:184)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:381)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:184)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:514 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:184)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:94)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:184)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3810)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:183)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:515 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:516 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[5/31/11 13:37:10:517 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebSphereInjectionProvider.inject(WebSphereInjectionProvider.java:51)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:517 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:207)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:517 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     ... 168 more
[5/31/11 13:37:10:517 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[5/31/11 13:37:10:518 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:1511)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:518 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.inject(WASAnnotationHelper.java:261)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:518 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.inject(WASAnnotationHelper.java:248)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:518 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebSphereInjectionProvider.inject(WebSphereInjectionProvider.java:49)
[5/31/11 13:37:10:518 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R     ... 169 more
[5/31/11 13:37:10:562 CDT] 00000126 SystemErr     R FATAL ERROR:  'java.lang.IllegalStateException: prepareThread not called for Thread Thread[WebContainer : 23,5,main]'
```

Comment: The answer is in the root cause of the stacktrace. Please post the entire trace.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean

This exception just means that the managed bean creation has failed because an error occurred during resource injection of the managed bean. Oh wait, that is what the exception is already telling.

Well, imagine that you've a `@Resource`, `@EJB`, `ManagedProperty`, etc annotation on the bean which is to be injected during bean's construction. When an exception occurs during construction of that resource, then you will get this exception.

However, at the bottom of the stacktrace you should find the details of the cause of the exception which occurred during creation of that resource. Fix *that* cause accordingly and it should work properly.

---

**Update**: finally, here is the answer, the bottommost part of the trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:1511)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.inject(WASAnnotationHelper.java:261)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.inject(WASAnnotationHelper.java:248)
     at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebSphereInjectionProvider.inject(WebSphereInjectionProvider.java:49)
     ... 169 more
```

This is clearly a bug in `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper` class. This is however outside your control, so you need to consult IBM for the fix. Digging in Google gives [some hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=Caused%20by%3a%20java.lang.NullPointerException%20at%20com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.inject) on this exception, among others an [official IBM bug report](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21383238&context=SSCQJHJ&cs=utf-8&lang=&loc=en_US). You can download fix packs [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PK83345).

Answer (score 1):

I recently got a similar error on a Java EE 6/JSF application running on Weblogic 12c.

Whenever I try to edit the JSF backing bean, "UsersController", and then rebuild using maven, I would get this:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean usersController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)

...

weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.inject(WebComponentContributor.java:299)
    at com.bea.faces.WeblogicInjectionProvider.inject(WeblogicInjectionProvider.java:29)
    ... 62 more
**Caused by**: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [jpa.session.UsersFacade] is defined: No beans of type jpa.session.UsersFacade;
```

My **solution** was this: After building the application in Netbeans, I had to go into the Weblogic console and update the web application. That seemed to eliminate the error.

I've posted the symptoms and the cure. If anyone knows the "why" to this problem, feel free to chime in.