# How to assign action to dynamic CommandButton in jsf using ActionExpression?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is my sample code

```
CommandButton save = new CommandButton();
        save.setValue("Save");
        save.setActionExpression(createActionExpression("#{controller.saveData}", String.class));



private MethodExpression createActionExpression(String actionExpression, Class<?> returnType) {

     FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
            facesContext.getELContext(), actionExpression, returnType, new Class[0]);
}

public void saveData(){

  }
```

My question is how to pass parameter to this function 
like ?

```
save.setActionExpression(createActionExpression("#{controller.saveData('str')}", String.class));


 public void saveData(String str){

  }
```

I have this error

```
javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{controller.saveData('str')}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: How exactly does your attempt fail?

Comment: first case without parameters is working ok no problem but when adding parameters it does not work

Comment: I didn't ask that. How exactly does it "not work"? Describe "does not work" elaborately. What exactly happens instead? You're acting like your car has a flat tire and you call a car mechanic and you only say "my car does not work". This is just unhelpful in order to diagnose the root cause of the problem.

Comment: ok this exception during load com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean

Comment: at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)

Comment: My exact question is how to call function with parameters using MethodExpression ??

Comment: *"ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean"* Finally something useful. It appears that you're not only new to JSF, but also to basic Java and can't read Java's exception stack traces yet. You need to look at the bottomost "Caused By" part of the stack trace. That part explains the root cause of your problem. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192320

Comment: *"My exact question is how to call function with parameters using MethodExpression"* There's nothing wrong with your attempt as shown in the question, provided that you're using up to date software and can do exactly the same in plain XHTML/JSP instead of Java, so something else is at matter and that can only be understood by carefully investigating the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for help but i think that you did not see my update in  the question getting this error

Comment: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{controller.saveData('str')}

Comment: so if i did the right why such error is caused

Comment: Are you implying that it works just fine in XHTML or JSP or whatever view technology you're using? It's important to realize that there's basically **nothing** which is impossible in XHTML/JSP and only possible in verbose and brittle Java code this way.